# Does Nespresso contain sugar?

Tags: sugar, nespresso, capsule

I've been told that Nespresso capsules contains sugar, but the site [Caffeineinformer.com](http://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-content/nespresso-coffee-capsules) says it doesn't. Are there any official sources that declares no sugar in Nespresso capsules?

Comment: There is sugar listed on the ingredients of my pods. It drives me crazy because I dont like sugar in my coffee

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Coffee is a pure and natural product, consisting only of water and
>   roasted coffee bean extract. Unsweetened black coffee is naturally low
>   in calories ( <1 kcal). No additives are present in our capsules.
>   Adding milk to the coffee can bring additional nutritional benefits to
>   the coffee. Milk is a good source of various essential nutrients.
>   Nevertheless, milk, cream and sugar provide calories which might
>   become significant if regularly consumed.

Reference: https://www.nespresso.com/us/en/grands-crus-coffee-range (FAQ; see bottom of the page)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to their company's assertion, I can say that I have cut open and inspected the ground coffee in many nespresso capsules, across many lines.

I have looked at the grind before use, and after.  There is no sugar in the media.  If there were any, it would be a form of coating or impregnation — and then I doubt the possibility, for it would interfere with the production of the coffee.

If there  were a large granule, it would appear different from other granules.  Small granules would separate differently and be apparent.

The used pods do not lose an mass / material, in the way that many k-cups do.  There are many k-cups types that, after using, weight much less because the hot water has dissolved the contents (sugar and hydrogenated oils) and delivered them to your cup.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Nespresso FAQs](https://www.nespresso.com/us/en/service-faq), and look for "Does Nespresso offer flavored coffee?", you will see this:

In addition, our flavored Holiday Limited Editions are exquisitely designed using all-naturally extracted ingredients, with no added sugars or preservatives.

That is the only thing I could find on Nespresso's web site, however I believe that indeed, Nespresso pods are very high quality and explicitly do not contain sugar unless mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A nespresso contains 100% ground coffee.It is not instant,and it does not contain any kind of additives.

Comment: Elaine, welcome! Please take a moment for the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [answer]. Unlike standard web forums you may be familiar with, we are a Q/A site with a quite different format. Oh, one personal suggestion: Don’t post photos that are unrelated to the question or answer.